# HTTP2 NodeJS server push stream does not finish

Tags: http2, server-push

I'm testing different server push scenarios in NodeJs for HTTP2 with node-spdy. Everything works fine until I try to push resources larger than 6MB. 4/6 pushed resources larger than 6MB are for instance received correctly but for 2/6 resources, no more than 6MB reaches the browser. Chrome developer tools network tab gives the message

"CAUTION: request is not finished yet!" while "Reading Push"

See screenshot:
https://i.gyazo.com/2b774b6c1410a6752c002003a800c637.png

I also wonder how I can change the SETTINGS called SETTINGS_MAX_FRAME_SIZE to be larger than the default 2^14 since this might be an issue for larger files I suppose. Documentation says that the client and server are able to set this value for each specific connection but I don't understand where this can be done.

Any ideas and thoughts on this are appreciated!

Thanks

**UPDATE**:

The problem was the `settings.initial_window_size` in /spdy-transport/connection.js. The initial window size is 6MB and therefore it wont push larger resources, but this only appears in Chrome, it doesn't affect Firefox.

Comment: If it doesn't work with the default window size setting but works with a higher one then something is broken in one of the participants - which means either the browser sends no window updates or the node server doesn't react on them. I would normally guess it's the latter one, since Chrome should have a now well-tested implementation. However if it works with Firefox it may also be a Chrome bug. If everything works correctly then the transfer should work even with an initial window size of 1byte, even though it may take a little bit longer.

Comment: The same also applies for the MaxFrameSize setting, it should work independent of it's value

Comment: Update: If I think more about it then your fix doesn't even make sense. The window size you can configure on your local side only changes how much bytes can be sent to your application. The amount that you can send to the browser is determined by it's window size, which is set to the default value (64kb) at the beginning and then transmitted from the browser to you in a settings frame.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! So your last comment suggests that Chrome transmits the limit of 6MB in the beginning in a settings frame, which causes the error. The `settings.initial_window_size` is the value that the browser should change, but which I force to change as a setting larger than 6MB to be able to push more resource to the browser. When I try to push more resources for instance, resource 3 works fine but not 1 and 2 which would indicate that Chrome (first?) SETTINGS frame isn't set properly in the node-spdy implementation...Maybe I can ask about the issue in the github repo.

Comment: The only thing I can think of which makes sense for my fix is that the implementation in node-spdy has a bug when applying the first couple of SETTINGS frames received from Chrome.